# Сумма select с одинаковыми значениями

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть три выпадающих списка, value суммируются (тут все считает правильно)

```
<select name="model_krovat" id="model">
    <option value="6300">Белава</option>
    <option value="7000">Купе</option>
</select> 
<select class="form-control" name="shirina_krovat" id="shirina">
    <option   value="0">600</option>
    <option   value="1000">1000</option>
    <option   value="1000">1100</option>
</select>  
<select class="form-control" name="dlina_krovat" id="dlina">
    <option value="500">1900</option>
    <option value="1000">2000</option>
    <option value="1000">2100</option>
</select
```

Выводится сумма значений выпадающего списка и чекбокса

```
<h4>Стоимость: </h4>
<span id="final_price">6300</span>  Руб.
$('#final_price').html(sum);
```

Чекбокс прибавляет к `sum` значения

```
<label for="yslygi">Нанесение краски       
<input type="checkbox" id="yslygi" />`
```

Код

```
var sum = 0;
```

сумма селектов

```
$('select').each(function() {
    sum += parseInt($(this).val());
});
```

подcчет значении чекбоксов. Но одинаковые значения: `value="1000"`, к сумме добавляет `100` и `300`, хотя нужно чтобы добавлялось к сумме, например, `100`.(Значения не могу поменять по заданию)

```
if ($("#yslygi").is(':checked')) {
    if ($('#shirina').val() == "600") sum += 100;
    if ($('#shirina').val() == "1000") sum += 100;
    if ($('#shirina').val() == "1000") sum += 300;
    if ($('#dlina').val() == "500") sum += 100;
    if ($('#dlina').val() == "1000") sum += 200;
    if ($('#dlina').val() == "1000") sum += 300;
}
```

Comment: если честно, я  не понял сути вопроса. Если вам не нравится что добавляет два раза, то удалите ненужную строку.

Comment: Вообще тупняк какой-то.

Comment: извините!при выборе модели Белава "6300", выбираю ширину "1000" в сумме выдает 7300,это верно.Нажимаю на чекбокс "нанесение краски" он должен прибавить  к сумме 100, а добавляет 400 (sum += 100; sum += 300;).То есть считает все значения для "1000" и складывает вместе,а надо отдельно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверяйте тогда по тексту если он, в отличие от value, уникален

```
if ($("#yslygi").is(':checked'))
{
  switch ($('#dlina option:selected').text())
  {
    case "1900" : sum+=100; break;
    case "2000" : sum+=200; break; 
    case "2100" : sum+=300; break;
  };
  switch ($('#shirina option:selected').text())
  {
    case "600" : sum+=100; break;
    case "1000": sum+=100; break; //точно 100? выглядит нелогично
    case "1100": sum+=300; break;
  }
}
```

Comment: То что нужно!Спасибо!!!

Comment: @Лиана не забывайте принимать ответ если ваша проблема решена